# Nginx - Wordpress blog on Rails loads styles and scripts with mime type text/html

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx, mime-types

I just installed a Wordpress blog under a /blog directory within a Rails app, running on Unicorn and Nginx, and my stylesheets and scripts aren't being loaded properly in the browser when I go to my domain.com/blog pages. Chrome console's giving me the following error:

- Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
- Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Have been trying to figure this out and tried out lots of solutions here on SO, but still can't get through... seems like there needs to be something changed on my Nginx config, particularly for the blog/php location. Here's my config:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.domain.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /home/dcs/htdocs/domain/current/public;

  access_log /home/dcs/htdocs/domain/log/access.log;
  error_log  /home/dcs/htdocs/domain/log/error.log;


  location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME home/dcs/htdocs/domain/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }


  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a ton of searching around, I finally found [this solution](https://tjosm.com/3128/nginx-rewrite-rules-wordpress-subdirectory-ruby-rails-app/).

Seems like the issue was that I needed to add a root to the app within "location /blog" and nest the "location ~ .php$" within /blog. Here's my Nginx config that's working now for a Wordpress blog in a Rails app using Unicorn, in case anyone else needs it:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.domain.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /home/dcs/htdocs/domain/current/public;

  access_log /home/dcs/htdocs/domain/log/access.log;
  error_log  /home/dcs/htdocs/domain/log/error.log;

  location /blog {
    root /home/dcs/htdocs/domain;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;

      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME home/dcs/htdocs/domain/$fastcgi_script_name;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ensure you have a `types` directive defined in your nginx config.

```
Syntax:     types { ... }
Default:    

types {
    text/html  html;
    image/gif  gif;
    image/jpeg jpg;
}

Context:    http, server, location
```

Maps file name extensions to MIME types of responses. Extensions are case-insensitive. Several extensions can be mapped to one type, for example:

```
types {
    text/css                     css;
    application/javascript       js;
    application/json             json;
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types

Comment: To expand, if your javascript and css files load fine outside of /blog path, I would suggest searching your nginx config files (both primary nginx.conf and any virtualhost files) for "mime.types" (no quotes). You should have an include for this file in top-level configuration (ie: nginx.conf). It's almost sounding like the mime types are somehow being loaded conditionally only outside /blog. I've never seen a configuration that causes the issue you are detailing. Your "location /blog" with try_files directive is perfect, should be serving static files normally.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I currently have "include mime.types" in my nginx.conf and that mime.types file has the types directive with css/javascript/etc, that you mentioned, Tan. I even tried doing "include /etc/nginx/mime.types" in that particular vhost inside the /blog and /php locations, but still no luck...

Comment: Nate - yes, my styles and scripts are all loading properly outside of "location/blog", but any pages in this Wordpress blog keep running into this mime type error for some reason.